# How to get incremental recoverage with Jacoco

Tags: java, unit-testing, jenkins, jacoco, test-coverage

I want to get a incremental code coverage report with Jacoco.
I modified some codes and it can get an incremental code coverage. But I got a problem.

```
1.I deploy a app(v1) and test "A" file 0-100 line codes, then I got a report(r1).
2.I modified some bugs(v2) and test "A" file 0-10 lines(verify a bug),then test 101-200 line codes, then I got a report(r2).
```

I want to merge r1 and r2 reports to show that I'm already test "A" file 0-200 lines.Does anybody has some idea?